# I'm here for your Confession - What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I'm here for your confession,
And I'm found in a progression,
I might be found in a creamery,
I'm also named for a deity,

You seldom work when I'm around,
Which has me feeling kinda blue,
So you ate me by the ocean side,
While the salty air gently blew.

Hint:

> When you ate me I was cold.

Hint 2:

> I shouldn't be interpreted as being salty.

Due to lack of tries, and this is probably too much, but:

> When you're done with play, I'm yesterday.

Comment: Did I literally eat the item in question?

Comment: Yes a person or you would have.

Comment: well Imma go and cross reference food and deity names, hopefully that turns up something

Comment: If I can figure out what that means, I'll keep it in mind

Comment: That probably refers to Poseidon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you perhaps

> Sunday / sundae?

I'm here for your confession,

> At a church, on a Sunday.

And I'm found in a progression,

> Days of the week.

I might be found in a creamery,

> A sundae is a kind of ice cream.

I'm also named for a deity,

> Many religions have, one way or another, worshipped the sun.

You seldom work when I'm around,

> Sunday is a day of rest in many parts of the world.

Which has me feeling kinda blue,

> Not sure whether there's any specific clue here. (But the so-called "blue laws" were all about forbidding various activities on Sundays.)

So you ate me by the ocean side,

> Sundae again (though I'm a bit unconvinced here; usually the ice creams you'd eat by the seaside are simple cones, and sundaes are more often served indoors in some kind of dish.)

While the salty air gently blew.

> If there's a specific clue here, I'm not seeing it.

Hint 1:

> "When you ate me I was cold": sundae again.

Hint 2:

> "I shouldn't be interpreted as being salty": is this just forestalling guesses at the wrong kind of food?

Hint 3:

> "When you're done with play, I'm yesterday.": on a Monday, when the working week resumes, Sunday is yesterday.

Comment: Very good. Unfortunately what appears to have misled you, and no doubt others, was supposed to be a significant clue. Blue/Blew, with your assertion that it references blue laws. The hint, not being salty, I was hoping would put more focus on the homonym which was the line's only purpose.

Comment: So the "salty air gently blew" was just indicating "blue" again, same as the line two earlier?

Comment: The salty air brought with it a homonym, maybe. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll bite, are you:

> Some type of Minerva cheese? Feta or something?

I'm here for your confession,
And I'm found in a progression,
I might be found in a creamery,
I'm also named for a deity,

> Cheese can be found in a creamery, Minerva was the Roman goddess of crafts and wisdom (and also supposedly a cheese brand). Cheese is produced in stages (a progression?).

Some have said that I don't work,
Which has me feeling kinda blue,
So, you ate me by the ocean side,
While the salty air gently blew.

> The production of cheese usually involves "Ripening", where the cheese will simply rest (don't work) so its flavor can be enhanced. This can last from weeks to years. Some cheese turns blue due to enough humidity that allows bacteria to grow.

Comment: So, I may have to add another verse. But, it's not cheese. I'll add a hint. Good answer.